Why do we need to marginalize when finding p(data) when latent variables are involved? (part of elbo derivation)
so confused with the derivation of elbo.  In part of the derivation p(data) is intractable as it involves an integral over a high dimensional latent variable.  I cant understand why the latent variable is involved when calculating p(data).  For images as an example why isnt p(a particular image) = 1 / the total number of images in the dataset?  I am not sure why the latent variable is involved when calculating p(data) since it is not on the left side of the equation and we are providing the dataset so we should know everything about the data.
any help is much appreciated

looks like the answer is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/why-break-down-the-denominator-in-bayes-theorem

Obviously only global parameters are not enough to derive the density p(x) for any continuously valued image data even from an image class say dogs for your image example, thus joint local latent variables are required to be integrated out to derive it. Due to same reason, your empirical probability isn't helpful here for pure MLE at all with a huge gap filled by the latents and we intuitively know p(x) must be much much smaller than most of your sampled empirical probabilities.
